# find out filesystem size and name on which specific directory is lying

Tags: c, linux

I need to find out the name of the `filesystem` and `mount directory` name from a given subdirectory name on LINUX(CentOS 5.4).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/vfs.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct statfs ls_tbs_fs;
    statfs(argv[1], &ls_tbs_fs);

    printf("TOTAL DISK KB : %lu\n", ls_tbs_fs.f_blocks*ls_tbs_fs.f_bsize/1024);
    printf("USED  DISK KB : %lu\n", (ls_tbs_fs.f_blocks-ls_tbs_fs.f_bavail)*ls_tbs_fs.f_bsize/1024);
    // I need filesystem here
    // I need mount point here
    return 0;
}
```

I want to do this without linux command like df. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `popen` have you heard?

Comment: I don't want to use any of linux command.

Comment: Well, if you want Linux-specific information on a Linux system, you're going to have to use some kind of Linux-specific command. Do you just mean you don't want use the shell? Are you looking for a library function?

Comment: Yes. library funtion is what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [stat(2),](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) [statfs(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html) and [statvfs(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statvfs.2.html). Then read and parse `/proc/self/mounts` and `/proc/self/mountstats`.

Try also to `strace df` to find out what syscalls it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

This only a partial answer to the questions in the original post.

You can find out the filesystem type that a path is lying on by [`statfs(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/statfs):

```
struct statfs {
    __SWORD_TYPE f_type; /* type of file system (see below) */
    __SWORD_TYPE f_bsize; /* optimal transfer block size */
```

Then you can convert this filesystem type to its name.

---

```
File system types:

ADFS_SUPER_MAGIC 0xadf5
AFFS_SUPER_MAGIC 0xADFF
BEFS_SUPER_MAGIC 0x42465331
BFS_MAGIC 0x1BADFACE
CIFS_MAGIC_NUMBER 0xFF534D42
CODA_SUPER_MAGIC 0x73757245
COH_SUPER_MAGIC 0x012FF7B7
CRAMFS_MAGIC 0x28cd3d45
DEVFS_SUPER_MAGIC 0x1373
EFS_SUPER_MAGIC 0x00414A53
EXT_SUPER_MAGIC 0x137D
EXT2_OLD_SUPER_MAGIC 0xEF51
EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC 0xEF53
EXT3_SUPER_MAGIC 0xEF53
EXT4_SUPER_MAGIC 0xEF53
HFS_SUPER_MAGIC 0x4244
HPFS_SUPER_MAGIC 0xF995E849
HUGETLBFS_MAGIC 0x958458f6
ISOFS_SUPER_MAGIC 0x9660
JFFS2_SUPER_MAGIC 0x72b6
JFS_SUPER_MAGIC 0x3153464a
MINIX_SUPER_MAGIC 0x137F /* orig. minix */
MINIX_SUPER_MAGIC2 0x138F /* 30 char minix */
MINIX2_SUPER_MAGIC 0x2468 /* minix V2 */
MINIX2_SUPER_MAGIC2 0x2478 /* minix V2, 30 char names */
MSDOS_SUPER_MAGIC 0x4d44
NCP_SUPER_MAGIC 0x564c
NFS_SUPER_MAGIC 0x6969
NTFS_SB_MAGIC 0x5346544e
OPENPROM_SUPER_MAGIC 0x9fa1
PROC_SUPER_MAGIC 0x9fa0
QNX4_SUPER_MAGIC 0x002f
REISERFS_SUPER_MAGIC 0x52654973
ROMFS_MAGIC 0x7275
SMB_SUPER_MAGIC 0x517B
SYSV2_SUPER_MAGIC 0x012FF7B6
SYSV4_SUPER_MAGIC 0x012FF7B5
TMPFS_MAGIC 0x01021994
UDF_SUPER_MAGIC 0x15013346
UFS_MAGIC 0x00011954
USBDEVICE_SUPER_MAGIC 0x9fa2
VXFS_SUPER_MAGIC 0xa501FCF5
XENIX_SUPER_MAGIC 0x012FF7B4
XFS_SUPER_MAGIC 0x58465342
_XIAFS_SUPER_MAGIC 0x012FD16D
```

Comment: The OP is calling `statfs` in his question.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I know, but it seems like the asker does not realize that `struct statfs` already include the file system type information he want.

Comment: I need fs name not type and How to get mount dir path?

Comment: @KIM You may need to convert this filesystem type to its name by yourself. To find out mount point, you may be like to check out [how does `df` do this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/df.c).